# Call JS function when see element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want call to function (animation) when I see element on display (scroll to element). I try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#count-repairs-all').on('show', function() { 
        alert('test'); 
    })
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. I can't find any plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
function isVisible(){
   //do something
alert(1);
}

//bind the  event with element
$('#contentDiv').bind('isVisible', isVisible);

//show div and trigger custom event in callback when div is visible
$('#contentDiv').show('slow', function(){
    $(this).trigger('isVisible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery` you can try this

```
var element = $('#yourDiv')
if(element.is(':visible')){
//Do some stuff
}
else{
//Do something else
}
```

Check out jQuery [DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
  var topOfCount =  $('#count-repairs-all').offset().top;
  if(scrollTop>topOfCount){
    // dosomeThing
  }
});
```